# Declaring types gives error in Haskell, but not declaring them is ok

Tags: haskell, types, numbers

When I `runhaskell` the following code:

```
f :: Num a => a -> a -> a
f x y = x*x + y*y

x = 3
y = 2.3
main = print (f x y)
```

Everything's fine. But when I add type declaration above the x and y assignment:

```
x :: Int
y :: Float
```

I get the error: "Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type`Float'".

I do understand that when declaring the type of `f` I'm imposing that x and y should be of the same type, and that is why I get the error. What I don't understand is why it works in the first case!

When I run the assignments in GHCi and inquire the type I get

```
Prelude> let x = 3
Prelude> :type x
x :: Integer
Prelude> let y = 2.3
Prelude> :type y
y :: Double
```

x and y, when the type is not declared, are interpreted  as numbers of different type! Why then does `f` not throw an error?

Comment: This sounds like a rather old version of GHCi. Recent versions turn off the monomorphism restriction by default *in interactive mode*, which makes them behave better.

Comment: I just downloaded the haskell platform using `sudo apt-get install haskell-platform` ...

Comment: It's probably old then. But the way to see is with `--version`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a confusing interaction of the following three things:

- Numeric literals in Haskell are polymorphic:

  ```
  Prelude> :type 3
  3 :: Num a => a
  Prelude> :type 2.3
  2.3 :: Fractional a => a
  ```
- [Monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction) forbids your `x` and `y` from being polymorphic.
- [Defaulting mechanism](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.3.4) makes it so that instead of giving you an "ambiguous type" error compiler tries its best to give your `x` and `y` a concrete type that works. In your ghci session different types work, but in your main program `Integer` doesn't work so it chooses `Double` for both.

Answer (score 2):

GHCi has special defaulting rules for numerical types in bindings directly defined in GHCi.

You should rather `:load` the module and then ask GHCi the type for the exported bindings:

```
> :load Foo.hs
> :type x
> :type y
```